# Evaluating the improper integral $\int_0^\infty k^3\left(k+\sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2}\right)e^{-\beta\left(k+\sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2}\right)}J_0(\rho k)\text{d}k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

While I was elaborating on a flow problem, I came across the following non-trivial improper integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty k^3 \left( k + \sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2} \right) e^{-\beta \left( k + \sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2} \right)} J_0 \left( \rho k \right)  \mathrm{d} k  
$$
wherein $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\rho$ are positive real numbers.
Here, $J_0$ denotes the zeroth-order Bessel function of the first kind.

For $\alpha = 0$ and for $\rho = 0$, the corresponding analytical expressions can easily be determined.

For the general case, I tried to use various integral definitions of the Bessel function. Unfortunately this did not seem to help.

I was wondering if someone here, who has expertise in those types of problems, could be of help and provide a few hints or suggestions to evaluate the above integral, that would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You may simplify it a little by letting $t=\alpha k$, $\gamma =\alpha \beta$ and $\sigma =\rho \alpha$. After that perhaps $t=\sinh u$ also helps.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for comment. I will try this hint immediately.

Comment: Another possible lead to follow would be to consider the Mellin transform. One has that the Mellin transform of $\int_0^{\infty} y^{\nu} f_1(xy)f_2(y)dy$ is $F_1(s)F_2(1-s+\nu)$ and the Mellin transform of $\mathcal{M}[J_{\nu}(x);s]=2^{s-1}\frac{\Gamma(s/2+\nu/2)}{\Gamma(\nu/2+1-s/2)}$. So if you can calculate $F_1(s) =\mathcal{M}[(k+\sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2})\exp(-\beta(k+\sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2}));s]$, you would at least have that the Mellin transform of the integral would be $2^{3-s}\frac{\Gamma(5/2-s/2)}{\Gamma(s/2-1/4)}F_1(s)$ which one then can try to invert. If this is a viable way, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AxelT Thanks Axel – Gary's approach does not seem to work unfortunately. I will try the Mellin-transform-based approach you outlined above and see if it works.

Comment: @AxelT Your idea looks promising but $F_1(s)$ is far from being within reach...

Comment: My suggestion was to make the integral look much simpler, which it does.

Comment: @Gary Then you probably meant $k=\alpha t$. The change of variable you mentioned complicates the expression further since we get exp of an exp. Thanks for the suggestion.